# RoR: named_scope, all records created within last 7 days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how do i define a named_scope to return all the records that were created within the last 7 days, and then how do i use that named scope in a controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend watching the [Railscast Episode on named_scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108).

Ideally, the code you're looking for would be:

```
 named_scope :recent, 
   lambda { |*args| {:conditions => ["created_at > ?", (args.first || 7.days.ago)]} }
```

This will allow you to pass a parameter to the named scope or it will default to the previous 7 days.

You would call it using:

```
MyModel.recent
```

Comment: I'm still new to Rails, but I absolutely *love* this feature!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass named_scope a proc so it will be evaluated every time the call to named_scope is run.  Otherwise if you specify Time.now it will run once (on first call) and be "cached" until the app is restarted.

```
  named_scope \
    :this_week,
    :conditions =>  [
      %created_at > :time!,
      proc {{:time => Time.now}}
    ]
```

You can call the named_scope like
@ar_object.this_week

Comment: that example throws errors. "unkown type of %string %created_at"

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for records which could return `last 7 days` i.e. not including today. But this worked for me and it can work for `last n days`.

```
scope :last_n_days, lambda {|n| where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today - n, Date.today - 1)}
```